# How can I retrieve <oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym> from every <rdf:Description> using OWL API

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

I am new to OWL API hence I am facing some issues for retrieving data.

Suppose I have the following data:

```html
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0044297">
        <oboInOwl:creation_date>"2010-02-05T10:37:16Z"</oboInOwl:creation_date>
        <obo:IAO_0000115>"The portion of a cell bearing surface projections such as axons, dendrites, cilia, or flagella that includes the nucleus, but excludes all cell projections."</obo:IAO_0000115>
        <oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace>"cellular_component"</oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace>
        <oboInOwl:hasDbXref>"Wikipedia:Cell_body"</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
        <oboInOwl:hasDbXref>"FMA:67301"</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
        <oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym>"cell soma"</oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym>
        <rdfs:label>"cell body"</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:subClassOf>http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0044464</rdfs:subClassOf>
        <oboInOwl:hasDbXref>"FBbt:00005107"</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
        <rdf:type>http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class</rdf:type>
        <oboInOwl:id>"GO:0044297"</oboInOwl:id>
        <rdfs:comment>"Note that 'cell body' and 'cell soma' are not used in the literature for cells that lack projections, nor for some cells (e.g. yeast with mating projections) that do have projections."</rdfs:comment>
        <oboInOwl:created_by>"xyz"</oboInOwl:created_by>
        <oboInOwl:inSubset>http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/go#goslim_pir</oboInOwl:inSubset>
    </rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0071509">
    <oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>"activation of MAPKK activity involved in mating response"</oboInOwl:hasRelatedSynonym>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0090028</rdfs:subClassOf>
    <oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace>"biological_process"</oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace>
    <oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym>"activation of MAP kinase kinase activity during conjugation with cellular fusion"</oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym>
    <oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym>"conjugation with cellular fusion, activation of MAPKK activity"</oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym>
    <rdfs:label>"activation of MAPKK activity involved in conjugation with cellular fusion"</rdfs:label>
    <rdf:type>http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class</rdf:type>
    <oboInOwl:id>"GO:0071509"</oboInOwl:id>
    <oboInOwl:creation_date>"2010-01-05T02:09:58Z"</oboInOwl:creation_date>
    <oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym>"conjugation with cellular fusion, activation of MAP kinase kinase activity"</oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym>
    <oboInOwl:created_by>"midori"</oboInOwl:created_by>
    <obo:IAO_0000115>"Any process that initiates the activity of the inactive enzyme MAP kinase kinase in the context of conjugation with cellular fusion."</obo:IAO_0000115>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0000186</rdfs:subClassOf>
</rdf:Description>
```

For each of the "rdf:description" I want to retrieve its corresponding "rdf:label", "oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym" and "rdfs:subClassOf" using OWL API in java.

So far I can get all labels but not the linkages as to which label is for which description.

Currently my code looks like:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology pizzaOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(f);
        Set<OWLOntology> allOntologies = manager.getImportsClosure(pizzaOntology);
        //System.out.println(allOntologies);
        OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new ElkReasonerFactory();
        OWLReasoner reasoner = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(pizzaOntology);
        //pizzaOntology
        OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();

        Set<OWLAxiom> axiom = pizzaOntology.getAxioms();
        for (OWLAxiom o : axiom) {
            AxiomType<?> at = o.getAxiomType();
            //System.out.println("Annotation type is "+at+" for "+o);

            if (at == AxiomType.ANNOTATION_ASSERTION) {
                OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom ax = (OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom) o;
                //Check if the axiom is a label and write to file
                if(ax.getProperty().toString().contains("hasExactSynonym"))
                System.out.println("Data is "+ax.getValue().toString());
                if (ax.getProperty().equals(factory.getRDFSLabel())) {
                    String label = ax.getValue().toString();
                    label = label.toLowerCase();
                    label = label.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+", " ");
                    allLabels.add(label);
                }
            }

        }
```

Can someone help me with some ideas about this?

Comment: Show the code that you have, I don't want to start from scratch here

Comment: Added the code in the edit

Comment: Ok, and what exactly doesn't work with the current code? You're iterating over all annotation axioms and if the URI of the property contains "hasExactSynonym" you print it.

Comment: Just as a comment, from the variable name one could think that you're loading the wrong ontology since it's called `pizzaOntology` and I don't know what the file `f` is refering to.

Comment: No, so this code works perfectly. Every time the property contains "hasExactSynonym" it prints and every time it's a rdfs:label it prints. What I want is to associate them, i.e for each description I want its corresponding label and "hasExactSynonym". In the two example XML, I showed both have a field of "hasExactSynonym" but that may not always be true. There may be certain definitions which do not have "hasExactSynonym".

Comment: To put it in even simpler terms , if I have a label "cell body" then I want to retrieve its corresponding "hasExactSynonym" and "subclassof" field, for which I need to associate the three terms which currently I am unable to do and that is my question.

Comment: I don't get it. You're a bit unclear. Note, in OWL there is no "rdf:description", this is just a tag of the RDF/XML serialization of an OWL ontology. In OWL you have classes, properties and individuals. So let me ask you again, do you want to have all classes with its corresponding labels and synonym (if exist)?

Comment: Sorry for the last reply. But shouldn't the XML contain owl:class tag to have an owl class. For the XML that I posted, I don't see any owl:class tag at all so how would I retrieve the properties? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you load the file with OWL API, I'm sure `http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0071509` will be a class, or not? And you want to have the labels for all classes or not? Note, if you load something in OWL API, we're talking about an OWL ontology, thus, there are classes, properties and individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLOntology pizzaOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(f);
    Set<OWLOntology> allOntologies = manager.getImportsClosure(pizzaOntology);
    // System.out.println(allOntologies);
    OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new ElkReasonerFactory();
    OWLReasoner reasoner = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(pizzaOntology);
    // pizzaOntology
    OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    Map<OWLAnnotationSubject, String> allLabels = new HashMap<>();
    Map<OWLAnnotationSubject, String> allExactSynonyms = new HashMap<>();
    for (OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom ax : pizzaOntology
        .getAxioms(AxiomType.ANNOTATION_ASSERTION)) {
        // Check if the axiom is a label and write to file
        OWLAnnotationSubject subject = ax.getSubject();
        if (ax.getProperty().toString().contains("hasExactSynonym")) {
            allExactSynonyms.put(subject, ax.getValue().toString());
        }
        if (ax.getProperty().equals(factory.getRDFSLabel())) {
            String label = ax.getValue().toString();
            label = label.toLowerCase();
            label = label.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]+", " ");
            allLabels.put(subject, label);
        }
    }
```

The two maps hold the relation between an IRI (the annotation subject in this case is always an IRI - annotation are attached to IRIs of classes, not to classes themselves) and the value of a property. If you match the label value with the value of a property for an IRI, you can find the other value through the IRI in the map.